# Firebase Snapshot Listener: Glide Illegal Argument Exception on Activity Destroyed (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase snapshot listener on my adapter. And, whenever the value updates the adapter is updated. But the problem is it tries to update even when the activity is destroyed.
It is crashing at `Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())` and the error is *You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity*
Yes, there are lots of related questions on stackoverflow. Must of them aren't possible in adapter. I also tried `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)`, `recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout()` on my fragment but none is working.

**Simplified adapter Code**

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final MessageClass model) {

    final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(model.getUser_receiver())
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {

                            ProfileClass profileClass = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObject(ProfileClass.class);
                                 String userId = queryDocumentSnapshots.getString("user_uid");

                            if(userId != null) {

                                    if (profileClass.getUser_image().equals("image")) {
                                        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.roundedImageViewChatsItemChatsImage);

                                    } else {
                                        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(profileClass.getUser_image()).into(holder.roundedImageViewChatsItemChatsImage);

                                    }
                                }
                                }

                        }

            });
```

**Logs**

```
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed 
 (RequestManagerRetriever.java:323)
 at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get (RequestManagerRetriever.java:132)
 at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get (RequestManagerRetriever.java:116)
 at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with (Glide.java:707)
 at com.meeti.all.Chats.ChatsFirestore$1.onEvent (ChatsFirestore.java:111)
 at com.meeti.all.Chats.ChatsFirestore$1.onEvent (ChatsFirestore.java:64)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.zza (SourceFile:497)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzd.onEvent (Unknown Source:6)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzh.zza (SourceFile:28)
 at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzi.run (Unknown Source:6)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I'm banging my head around this for a week.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option - 1:** As you need the data only once, you can use [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) like below:

```
firebaseFirestore
    .collection("users")
    .document(model.getUser_receiver())
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                //Rest of your code
            }
        }
    });
```

**Option - 2:** Add your `context` to `addSnapshotListener` like below:

```
firebaseFirestore
    .collection("users")
    .document(model.getUser_receiver())
    .addSnapshotListener(
        holder.itemView.getContext(), 
        new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() 
            {

            });
```

As stated in [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#public-methods_1):

> Starts listening to this query using an Activity-scoped listener.
>   The listener will be automatically removed during onStop().

Comment: I actually think this can be a better way. I'll check and let you know. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @SushanNiroula, Is this help you?

Answer (score 2):

You're requesting context of from **itemView**, but for asynchronous calls you should use app context, because context of view/fragment might not be available after the execution of that asynchronous call (in your case Glide image loading request).

To fix this issue, simply replace

```
holder.itemView.getContext()
```

with

```
holder.itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have heard `getApplicationContext()` eats up a lot of resources. Is that true?

Comment: This might help : [Context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189719/9045244)